tracking URL disappears when Spark3.5.1 runs on Hadoop3
spark2.4, spark3.3.0, spark3.4.3 or any version of spark below 3.5, their tracking URL show ok for the same community version apache hadoop-yarn-3.2.
But spark 3.5.1 directly just show the app id in spark-shell, or just the result if submitted by spark-submit, not any [ACCEPT] or [RUNNING] log or tracking URL.
Wonder why and how to resolve this.

